# Is there a way to configure the wireless keyboard to control the keyboard light?

Tags: keyboard

My Macbook Pro has a lit keyboard.

I can change the intensity of the keyboard light using Fn F5/F6 on the Macbook's keyboard.

My Apple Wireless [Keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Wireless_Keyboard), Third generation (A1314), has no markings on F5/F6 for changing the keyboard light.

Sure enough, pressing Fn F5/F6 on the wireless keyboard does not affect the keyboard light.

(Fortunately, changing the Macbook's display intensity and volume both work fine on the wireless keyboard, where the inscriptions on the keyboard say they should.)

Is there a way to configure the wireless keyboard to control the keyboard light?

Comment: You're talking about the Apple wireless keyboard, right?

Comment: After a quick visit to Wikipedia to survey the formal nomenclature. That's right. It's not the lithium battery Magic Keyboard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Keyboard) but the AA battery Apple Wireless Keyboard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Wireless_Keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

You would think this would be a simple task, such as simply designating a shortcut to a specific key combination for this action from System Preferences, but unfortunately it's not an option. You may have noticed that the actions themselves (dim, increase brightness, toggle backlight on/off) are not included in the 'Shortcuts' list in 'System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts' and therefore there isn't a way to configure them natively within the settings/preferences of OS X/macOS.

I have heard of a third party program called [LabTick](http://labtick.proculo.de/) that has helped to resolve this issue with users in the past, but it was developed for older operating systems and warns against it being unstable on a newer OS. I have confirmed the instability myself by installing it on macOS Sierra 10.12.2; the first time I launched it, it quit unexpectedly while trying to configure the shortcuts. When I was finally able to configure the shortcuts, they did not work for me even after trying multiple different key combinations.